# How to get the this instance in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

In vue 2+ I can easily get the instance of `this` as a result I can write something like this,

```
// main.js
app.use(ElMessage)

// home.vue
this.$message({
  showClose: true,
  message: 'Success Message',
  type: 'success',
})
```

What should I do for vue 3 as,

> Inside setup(), this won't be a reference to the current active
> instance Since setup() is called before other component options are
> resolved, this inside setup() will behave quite differently from this
> in other options. This might cause confusions when using setup() along
> other Options API. - vue 3 doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using `ElMessage` directly

ElementPlus supports using `ElMessage` the same way as `$message()`, as seen in this [example](https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/blob/575835a2f8fee87011144106c6124c96660a5c20/docs/examples/message/different-types.vue):

```js
import { ElMessage } from 'element-plus'

export default {
  setup() {
    const open1 = () => {
      ElMessage('this is a message.')
    }
    const open2 = () => {
      ElMessage({
        message: 'Congrats, this is a success message.',
        type: 'success',
      })
    }

    return {
      open1,
      open2,
    }
  }
}
```

#### Using `$message()`

Vue 3 provides `getCurrentInstance()` (an internal API) inside the [`setup()` hook](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#composition-api-setup). That instance allows access to global properties (installed from plugins) via `appContext.config.globalProperties`:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const globals = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties;
    return {
      sayHi() {
        globals.$message({ message: "hello world" });
      },
    };
  },
};
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-component-instance-in-setup-forked-ofmbbq?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue:169-247)

**Note:** Being an internal API, `getCurrentInstance()` could potentially be removed/renamed in a future release. Use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a different method where the idea is to set a globally scoped variable to the _component property of the viewmodel/app or component:

```
pageVM = Vue.createApp({
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        renderComponent: true,
                        envInfo: [],
                        dependencies: [],
                        userGroups: []
                    }
                },
                mounted: function () {
                    //Vue version 3 made it harder to access the viewmodel's properties.    
                    pageVM_props = pageVM._component;
                    this.init();
                },
```